# How to convert images in format List<File> to Bitmap?

Tags: list, image, file, bitmap

Please help me with converting List File to Bitmap? in android java.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45494283/how-to-convert-list-of-image-file-paths-into-list-of-bitmaps-quickly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ArrayList<Bitmap> bitmapArray = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();    
if(bitmapArray.size() > 0)
{
  int index = bitmapArray.size() -1;
  Bitmap lastbitmap = bitmapArray.get(index);
  SubImageView.setImageBitmap(lastbitmap);
}
```

Try this in a function

Comment: but how to convert List<File> to bitmap ?

Comment: `File saveBitmap; // Your image file
String filePath = saveBitmap.getPath();  
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);` Try this

Comment: thanks bro, I tried like this . Bitmap bitmap=decodeFile(saveBitmap.get(0).getAbsolutePath());